# python create csv & Excel open csv problem

Tags: python, excel, csv

I use python to create a csv which is UTF-8.  it use ',' as delimiter
then, i use excel to open the file even i press save it.
I use notepad++ open it again
It change delimiter ','  to \t [tab]

is that any excel setting problem?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show the Python code (or a small version of it) which recreates your problem